# What happen to a Wraith's belongings when it falls into a Harrowing?

Tags: world-of-darkness, wraith-the-oblivion

If a Wraith is reduced to zero temporal corpus dots, or if a fetter is destroyed, the corpus is temporally destroyed, and the bare soul is descended to the Labyrinth to confront a Harrowing.

What happen to the belongings that are not part of the poor soul's corpus? If the Wraith was carrying three oboli, a soulforged sword and a relic moustache's comb, do they go to the harrowing, do they fall where the Wraith was on the Shadowlands or Underworld, or do they fall into the Tempest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the description of "What Actually Happens in a Harrowing" (WtO2E, p.184)

> A Harrowing occurs when a wraith is dragged down by Oblivion for various reasons (see below) into the Labyrinth, there to become the temporary plaything of some Spectres working with her Shadow. As soon as one of the Harrowing conditions is met (endangerment of a Fetter or a Passion, etc.), a small Nihil opens directly underneath the character, and she descends at great speed through the Tempest.

Since the wraith is moving, as she would through the use of Argos, through the hyperspace of the Tempest, any goods she carries would be taken with her in the usual fashion into the Labyrinth. In the case of a Destruction Harrowing, I don't see any reason for the items to be left behind either, since the wraith reforms at a Fetter with one Corpus if they succeed. I'd imagine that a wraith who loses a Destruction harrowing has her goods lost in the Tempest, with the possibility of someone else finding them later at a random time.

Comment: WtO1E, p.184 (too): "The character gains a semblance of a body, although this is not his corpus: it is merely a mental projection". Is that still true in second edition? If yes, how could he carry his belongings if he has no body, being only a mental projection. And if he can keep them, does that mean he can use his sword during the harrowing?

Comment: Also a small correction: I think a Wraith who entered a Harrowing because of the lost of temporary Corpus is reformed with as many temp Corpus as Stamina.

Comment: That text isn't there in Second Edition: what it says instead is, "With even her tenuous hold on the reality of the Shadowlands being eroded, she stands on the verge of total dissolution." I think that, with the new edition, they strove to fix this problem; a Harrowing either moves a wraith bodily into the Labyrinth, or just triggers the roll. And I checked about the Corpus thing. "Success snaps her back to a Fetter (if she has any) or to a random part of the Tempest where she immediately recovers **a single point each** of temporary and permanent Corpus.

Comment: My fault, I misread you and didn't notice you were talking about destruction harrowing. I suppose that recovery is when a Wraith loses his last permanent Corpus point, and if he survives, he starts at 1/1. In other cases, Wraith start at Stamina or permanent Corpus, whichever is lower (page 232).

Comment: No worries. And the reason I focused on the destruction harrowing is, to my mind, that's the only one where the outcome is in question. In harrowings targeting a fetter or a passion, it's certain that you can bring your gear. Of course, since the goal of the harrowing isn't to destroy the spectral actors, but to roleplay out a scene involving what matters to you, the sword is unlikely to help.